# How to open local PDF file on iOS

Tags: unity, c#, ios, filesystem

I am using `Application.OpenURL`
to open pdf files in standalone desktop builds, but when I used iOS platform it simply did not work. Then, I found on [official docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html) that

> iOS: `Application.OpenURL` cannot be used for opening local files.

I am unable to find an alternative.I found [Yasir kula native file picker](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker) but that don't cover the file opening feature.

Comment: Is [Xamarin.Forms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-apps-syncfusion-pdf-viewer/) an option? SE also has some posts about Xarmin & PDF for iOS such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46208297/950488).

Comment: I am using Unity game-engine.

Comment: Yes, I saw Unity in the question tags. It's possible to [use Xamarin & Unity](https://github.com/arau-consulting/UnityView4Xamarin.Forms).